# Conditional formatting not displaying cell highlights on coworkers computer

Tags: excel, excel-2010

My boss has a spreadsheet that uses macros and conditional formatting to rearrange data and whatnot; he is running at least Office 2010. When my coworker opens it, however, it does not show cell fill colors; he is running 2007. It shows up on mine and I am also running 2010.

I am pretty Excel savy but this has me stumped.

[image]

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated. He leaves tomorrow and I need this running correctly before he leaves!

Comment: Does the colour filling rely on macros to create the fill / CF?  Are any macros working correctly for him?  Which editions of Office are you using - 32 / 64 bit?  Difficult to help with so little information.

Comment: Please include snippets of the macros and the conditional formatting rules.

Comment: Just thinking that "tomorrow" for you is eminent, the most expedient thing may be to update your co-workers computer's version of Exel to at least the version that you have. If the macros are running correctly and the issue is only the fill colors, you may want to make sure that the colors used are basic.

Comment: Well I just checked and there are no macros. I dont why he said there were. I automatically want to think that there is some sort of setting that wont allow him to see these fill colors. But he can manually fill them of course but they wont appear upon opening like they should

Comment: @clif, that is my suggestion that will most likely happen by the end of today. I included a snippet of some of the rules, most of them look similar to those

Comment: I see that $C3 is referring to another sheet - is it possible that it refers to something not accessible to your coworker? Do any of the rules refer to external workbooks perhaps? Also - do the rules appear in your co-worker's computer at all? Like, in his version of the file can you see that the rules are there? If so, spot check a cell that you would expect to hit a rule, and run the calc manually to see on his computer if it does.

Comment: Ya, I already thought of that. But we are all running off the same K: drive. We all have access to the same files and have the same save locations. It all works fine on my computer. I will check on his rules in just a few minutes, but the conditional formatting seems to have been working fine on his with except fill color, which is important for this document.

Comment: For Excel 2007, I'm pretty sure conditional formatting can't refer to another sheet. Same thing when creating drop-down boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel 2007, if your coworker wants the conditional formatting to work from another sheet, he is going to need to create a named range. Follow this link and scroll down a little to the "Conditional Formatting Workaround for Earlier Versions" section:

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/09/03/conditional-formatting-from-different-sheet/

Comment: Thank you, I believe this to be the problem. @rwilson, you pointed that out as well. I had a feeling that it was because he was using 2007 and that conditional formatting was not as advanced.